# How to set the cell background color for a TWTRTimelineViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, twitter-fabric

Does anyone know how to set the cell background color for a TWTRTimelineViewController?

I am using the Fabric framework

Usual methods like `cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()` don't work.

Class reference is available [here](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios-reference/twtrtweettableviewcell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for late reply, but hope it will help you or somebody.
You must override `willDisplayCell` delegate method in your `TWTRTimelineViewController` as follows:

For `swift` solution:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = cell as? TWTRTweetTableViewCell {
        cell.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
        cell.tweetView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
        // Do what you want with your 'tweetView' object
    }
}
```

For `Objective-c` solution:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(TWTRTweetTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.tweetView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    // Do what you want with your 'tweetView' object
}
```

Remember `TWTRTimelineViewController` is a subclass of `UITableViewController` which means that you could override all `tableView` delegate methods.

See https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios-reference/twtrtweettableviewcell for know what can you do with `cell` as `TWTRTweetTableViewCell` class instance.

Comment: Works, BUT, messes up the tableview at run time and causes weird behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out using the two functions below

```
TWTRTweetView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
TWTRTweetTableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

 cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more specified, I am using the Fabric framework which means that this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

write following lines in your code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
     cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more specified, I am using the Fabric framework which means that this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
cell.tweetView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

You can find more details on : https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/show-tweets

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more specified, I am using the Fabric framework which means that this doesn't work